# "ambiguous indirect export" error when I try to import multiple functions from the same module

Tags: javascript

I've been having issues with exporting and importing modules. I have a main file (main.js) depending on 3 modules (helpers.js, data.js, and menus.js) which all export multiple functions and variables. The modules also depend on each other. I've written the import and export statements exactly the way they're shown in the MDN docs, but every time I load the file I get an "ambiguous indirect export" error.

The import/export statements for each of the four files are as follows:

Export for helpers.js:

```
export {
    getValue, remove, classLister, classRemover, addClass
};
```

Import for data.js:

```
import { classLister } from './helpers.js';
```

Export for data.js:

```
export {
    validTags, wordOpts, phraseOpts, inputOpts, allOpts,
    wordMenu, phraseMenu, inputMenu, deselect, menu
};
```

Import for menus.js:

```
import { classLister, classRemover } from './helpers.js';
import { 
    validTags, wordOpts, phraseOpts, inputOpts, allOpts
} from './data.js';
import { deselect, menu } from './main.js';
```

Export for menus.js:

```
export {
    deselectorMaker, normalPos, remover, update, addPos,
    addWord, menuMaker, haceFrases, deshaceFrases
};
```

Import for main.js:

```
import {
    deselectorMaker, menuMaker, update, remover, addPos,
    haceFrases
} from './menus.js';
import {
    classRemover, classLister, addClass, getValue
} from './helpers.js';
import {
    wordMenu, phraseMenu, inputMenu, validTags, wordOpts,
    phraseOpts
} from './data.js';
```

I was able to get some things to work by importing * and using the module name before every function, but it's rather messy and causes some different issues so I would much rather import individual functions if possible. I've looked around and haven't found anyone else with this particular issue, the error generally seems to come from default functions and incorrect JSON formatting, neither of which I have.

Comment: You seem to import from `main.js` in `menus.js` and vice versa. I can imagine circular import references to be problematic, but I don't know for sure nor whether they are the problem in this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Organizing your code so that you do not have circular dependencies would be a really good idea.

Comment: Also you did not post the `export` section for the "main" file.

Comment: Removing circular imports fixed it! Thank you so much and sorry for any formatting/etiquette errors, I'll make sure to format better next time I ask something.

Answer (score 0):

[OP mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024069#comment134081910_76024069) that circular imports were the issue.

---

## Avoid circular imports

With circular imports: At the time of importing the second interdepending module, the first's exports are uninitialized. That second module imports the first's uninitialized exports, which (upon use) should result in a `ReferenceError`.

With indirect dependencies or transpiled code, the error (or warning) message may be different.

Usually it is best to **write code without circular dependencies**.

**Note**: This does not exclude circular *object references*, though note that e.g. [`JSON.stringify()` does not support such references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#issue_with_serializing_circular_references).

## How to avoid?

You should try to abstract the modules so that those abstractions are not interdependent:

- For modules, separate dependent from independent parts; add more modules when necessary.
- For classes, [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) or [composition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#avoiding_inheritance) may be useful.
- For functions, [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) or [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) may be useful.

---

I found a [post about Circular Dependencies](https://codeinfocus.com/blog/2021-09/circular-dependencies/#how-to-avoid--fix-circular-dependencies) whose summary I enjoyed:

> Having circular dependencies in your code, is
> pretty much [indicative of] an incorrect organization of your code base.
> (...) Consider splitting into smaller modules,
> using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (and more).